# Access folder through web application IIS

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis, application-pool

I have a web application that uses an excel template to generate an excel with data for a user 
it's working on my localhost 
How do I setup IIS for the application to be able to access the template, generate the excel file and delete without having access denied ?
knowing that I want the folder to be in inetpub/reporting
The application pool identity is network service

Thank you

Comment: Could you please post more details description about how to access the template and generate the excel in asp.net core?  Which folder you used to save and access the excel?

Comment: it worked, I have created a folder reporting under inetpub , and gave access to the application pool identity the read and write access :)

Comment: I'm glad that you have solved it by yourself, I suggest you could post a reply and mark it as answer.